# Как выводить динамические пути к фотографиям которые хранятся на компъютере с помощью thymeleaf?

Tags: java, веб-программирование, hibernate, mvc, thymeleaf

Потратив сутки на жалкие попытки решения проблемы, я пришел к выводу, что фотографии не загружаются из-за разного бинарного кода, или из-за чего-то подобного.

Дело в том, что когда я прописываю путь к фотографии в базе данный, в тупую:

```
private String mainPhoto = 'путь к фотографии'
```

то всё работает и фотографии грузятся, но когда я его добавляю динамически через сеттеры, то он сохраняется и добавляется в базу и из неё достается.

И достаётся он таким же без каких либо изменений, кроме бинарного кода, он другой (это я высмотрел в дебагере).

Нужно ли создать специальный `break point("/image/id=1")` для обработки запросов?

Если да, то поделитесь ссылкой на материал где можно об этом почитать[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не загружаются на странице  или в базу ?, addResourceHandlers настроили ? Что у Вас происходит не совсем понятно.

Comment: А где эти фотографии хранятся?